# Verificar si existe al menos un elemento de varios en un array

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando `includes` para saber si el elemento existe en mi array:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.includes(1)
Console => true
```

Todo muy bien, pero ahora trato de poner más opciones a la función `includes`

¿Cómo verificar que existe por lo menos un elemento de varios en el array?

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.includes(0,2,3,8)
```

Como podemos ver el 2 y 3 existen en nuestro array, pero si ejecuto esto me sale `false`.

```
array.includes(0,2,3,8)
Console => false
```

Comment: `includes()` ya verifica si por lo menos existe un elemento

Comment: Así es, pero yo intento saber si existe por lo menos uno de los elementos. Si mando 2 existentes me da FALSE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Si quieres chequear si existe **por lo menos algún elemento** puedes usar [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) que devuelve **`true`** o **`false`** dependiendo si se cumple la condición que estableces en la función o no.

`find()`, a diferencia de `some()` devuelve **el valor del primer elemento que coíncide**, de manera que tienes que chequear el `lenght` del resultado, por dicha razón, para este problema específico entiendo que es mejor `some()`.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var valoresAchequear = [0, 1, 2]; //<-- checkeamos si existe alguno de estos

console.log(array.some(e => valoresAchequear.includes(e)));
console.log(array.some(e => e === 6)); //<-- no esta incluido

//si usamos las llaves hay que poner el return
console.log(array.some(e => {
  if (e === "algo" || e === 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías usar la función `find()` y si encuentra una coincidencia en alguna de sus iteraciones retornará tal número, luego de ello podrías cambiar ese número a su expresión `boolean`.

```js
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var values = [0,2,3,8]

const isIncluded = values.find(value => array.includes(value))

console.log(isIncluded === 0 || !!isIncluded)
```

**Actualización**: hecha la validación para cuando el valor encontrado es 0, ya que no aplicaría hacer el casteo `!!`.

Comment: Justo es lo que intento hacer, gracias!

Comment: de hecho es más óptimo que obtener la `length` de coincidencias, porque apenas encuentre saldrá de la función.

Comment: que pasa si `var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`, devuelve **false**, que es incorrecto, para arreglarlo tendrías que hacer length, por esa razón deberías usar `some()` como pongo en mi respuesta. El problema es que find() devuelve el match.

Comment: si `find()` no encuentra el match asigna `undefined` a `isIncluded` y eso casteado a su valor `boolean` es `false`.

Comment: claro, lo que digo es:  que pasa si lo encuentra, y el valor es 0

Comment: @Marz Fijate este ejémplo https://jsfiddle.net/ethxrbyk/

Comment: Verdad, aún existiendo los valores 2 y 3 me retorna FALSE.

Comment: @Emeeus buen punto ahí actualizo la validación para el caso 0.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es saber si existe algún elemento dentro de tu array lo mas sencillo seria usar

```
array.length
```

Esto te devolvera el numero de elementos que posees dentro de tu array, y para saber si un elemento en especifico se encuentra podria usar

```
array.indexOf()
```

Tambien seria una opción aunque trabaja de manera distinta a includes hace básicamente la misma funcion, aunque el la funcion includes es mas nueva...

Comment: array.indexOf() Sirve solo para comparar solo un elemento existente en el array, no puedo realizar lo siguiente:  array.indexOf(0,10)

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes verificar con `Array.length` asi:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(array.includes(1))

var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(array.length > 0)
```

Comment: No es la respuesta que estoy buscando, no intento saber si existen elementos en el array, lo que intento es comparar si por lo menos un elemento existe en el array, con include mando dos parametros que existen en el array y me retorna FALSE.

Comment: ¿por que siempre responden sin leer la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede buscar si existe tal elemento a manera de matriz mediante `map`.

Con el array `[0,2,3,8]` se puede preguntar por cada uno. ¿Está incluyendo el 0? ¿y el 2? ¿y el 3? ¿y el 8? dentro de `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Esto, lo que hace es preguntar por todos, y queda un array como el siguiente:

```
[
    false, // ¿Incluye el 0?
    true, // ¿Incluye el 2?
    true, // ¿Incluye el 3?
    false // ¿Incluye el 8?
]
```

Por último se puede preguntar si en el array existe `true`, que en este caso es cierto.

Código:

```js
var existe_alguno = (a,b)=>b.map(x=>a.includes(x)).includes(true)
console.log( existe_alguno( [1,2,3,4,5] , [0,2,3,8] ) )
```